# Properties of Inverse Lambert W function

Tags: special-functions

Starting with the two-branched [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (from Wikipedia):

[image]

Suppose we just flip it like this:

[image]

Is there a single power series for this $y=W^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lambert W function, $y=W(x)$ is a solution for $y \mathrm{e}^y = x$. Hence $W^{-1}(y) = y \mathrm{e}^y$.